# Azure GitHub - Choose which project to deploy

Tags: azure, github, continuous-integration, devops

My Solution consist of two projects:
-One is a regular asp.net mvc web front end
-a webapi...

When i use azures "Deployment Options" or "Continuos Delivery Preview" I cannot choose which one i want to make available at that specific slot/app.

I don't know why but the web app is always the one that gets deployed.

I already tried setting the default start-up project

How can I do that?
How can i tell azure which project to use on that slot/app?
is that a in-solution configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by setting up the project publish on the build definition. The box becomes available once you uncheck the "publish web projects"